# mobilefirst js starts with ionic serve (WL is not defined)

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ibm-mobilefirst

**Objective:**
Get `mfpjsloaded` in `document` event
way to check: `this.renderer.listen('document', 'mfpjsloaded', () => {});` in `app.component.ts`

---

Many get `WL is not defined reference` error using `mobilefirst` and `ionic serve`.
And i see no solution out there.
However, i have a project on hand that can start mfp script with `ionic serve`.
I am sorry that i cannot share code with you.
With a brand new project, i find i cannot start mfp script with `ionic serve` anymore.

---

**Known workaround:**
1. use `mfpdev app preview`
2. use emulator / device
**Please **DO NOT** suggest those in your reply

---

**Finding:**
To kick start `mfp js`, it needs `worklight js` to be run

---

Hope to see suggestions.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This occurs if MFP components are not loaded before your execution starts to use MFP commands. The workaround is to ensure that you use MFP APIs only after MFP load is complete. This can be achieved in 2 ways :

1. Call MFP functions form within the function wlcommoninit() . Usage of this function would be similar to the usage in this link : https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/application-development/sdk/cordova/
2. Use the event 'mfpjsloaded'. Only after the trigger of this event, use MFP functionalities. This event can be used this way : `document.addEventListener('mfpjsloaded', initWL, false);`.
   Add your MFP functions in `initWL` function.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The first way is a manual init which is not suitable in the project. (and i see no manual init needed in the project i said, starting mobilefirst client in ionic serve) For the second method, it looks the same as in the question: listening to mfpjsonjsloaded event. The problem is no mfpjsonjsloaded event fired.